# Node.js, wordpress,redis

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redis

I need to get data from Redis in node server and send it to a Wordpress layout. I tried the following, but `data` doesn't seem to get sent.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient(); //creates a new client

client.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('connected');
});

data = [];

client.set(['first', 'Oleh']);
client.set(['second', 'Ivan']);
client.set(['thirt', 'Andriy']);
client.set(['fourth', 'Olena']);
client.set(['fifth', 'Kristy']);
client.set(['sixth', 'Irina']);

client.get('first', function (err, reply) {
    console.log(reply);
    data.push(reply);
});

client.get('second', function (err, reply) {
    console.log(reply);
    data.push(reply);
});

client.get('thirt', function (err, reply) {
    console.log(reply);
    data.push(reply);
});

client.get('fourth', function (err, reply) {
    console.log(reply);
    data.push(reply);
});

client.get('fifth', function (err, reply) {
    console.log(reply);
    data.push(reply);
});

client.get('sixth', function (err, reply) {
    console.log(reply);
    data.push(reply)
});

app.get('http://localhost/wordpress/', function (req, res) {

    res.type('application/json'); // set content-type
    res.send(this.data); // send text response
    console.log(this.data);
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 4730);
```

Comment: Can you show us what you [have now](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Edit your question, and add it in there please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have the scope incorrect. `this.data` refers to the `function (req, res) {}` and not your global scope.

Try doing `res.json(data)` and remove the `res.type()`, as `res.json` already takes care of that for you.

Comment: If I go to url "http://localhost:4730/" I get json and saw in page, but if I send data in wordpress nothing

Comment: Problems like this are usually not easily solved. At least you've solved one thing now, try asking a new question that gives more details about your Wordpress set up, plugins and what you are trying to achieve.